# Entity Framework Core FromSqlRaw mock test cases

Tags: c#, integration-testing, dbset, mockdbset

I am creating a integration test for api method which have some query like below

```
public async static Task<IEnumerable<T>> ForSysAll<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet,int id) where T : class
{
    return await dbSet.FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName Where Id = {0}",id).ToListAsync();
}
```

This is working fine while I run with API code. But when I am trying to debug/run with test case. It throws an exception which is :-   `System.NotImplementedException : Unhandled method: FromSqlOnQueryable`

Can anyone having any idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InMemory database is not a relational database and doesn't support raw SQL execution.
[Link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19005).